# Find files by name in range using regex or name

Tags: linux, find, regular-expression

I have multiple screenshots since 2008 with name like "screenshot-2010-13-12.jpg". I need to copy screenshots since 2010 to 2019. I tried different options with -name and -regex , but cant find the way. The only success with regex is finding by format, nothing more.

Comment: cp screenshot-201* whereever

Comment: @ThorstenStaerk, this will find also `screenshot-201aaa.doc`

Comment: find -iname "screenshot-201[0123]" will show you all files named screenshot-2010 screenshot-2011 till screenshot-2013. You can refine this search to adhere to your exact format. Where are you struggling?

Comment: @ThorstenStaerk, this will find also `Screenshot....`, `screenshot-2013`, but not `screenshot-2019-13-12.jpg`. And will show also the directories.

Comment: @RomeoNinov what directories?

Comment: @roaima, the command, proposed by Thorsten Staerk, will list also directories.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to be strict about the format something like this can do the work:

```
find . -name "screenshot-201[0-9]-??-??.jpg" -type f
```

This will search for files whose name starts with `screenshot-201`, then has a digit, then dash, two characters, dash, two characters and `.jpg`

Answer (score 1):

To generalise to arbitrary range of dates, in `zsh` you could do:

```
cp screenshot-????-??-??.jpg(.e['
  [[ $REPLY >= screenshot-2010-02-12.jpg &&
     $REPLY <= screenshot-2019-09-21.jpg ]]']) /some/dir/
```

Or:

```
cp screenshot-????-??-??.jpg(.e['
  [[ ${REPLY//[^0-9]} = <20100212-20190921> ]]']) /some/dir/
```

To copy regular (with `.`) files in the 2010-02-12 to 2019-09-21 range for instance.

If they're not in the current working directory but you need to search for them in any level of subdirectories:

```
cp -i -- **/screenshot-????-??-??.jpg(.e['
  [[ $REPLY:t >= screenshot-2010-02-12.jpg &&
     $REPLY:t <= screenshot-2019-09-21.jpg ]]']) /some/dir/
```

(here adding `-i` to mitigate the risk in case several files with the same name are found in directories).